# No option "Open with" when right clicking in VS Code (Liveserver is installed)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

[image]

When right clicking in a HTML file in VS Code, I can't find the option to run the file.

I already did it before, but then, I coded using php, Python and Java on VS Code, and now I cannot anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know the reason to this. Try to use a shortcut to open live server if right clicking doesn't work. Go to command palette and see the shortcut for live server.